# What does it mean when you have Span ($s$) when $s$ is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

As far as I know usually Span is noted with the finite set of vectors with which I can span the whole vector space.

For example in $R2$ obviously this is a span $Sp((1,0) , (0,1))$.

But I have a hard time understanding what it means when you put the vector space itself in the closure.

I have seen it quite a lot in questions when instead of writing a finite set of vectors they put in closures the vector space or subspace. 
Maybe they mean that the basis of that vector space should be the span? I am not sure.  Can you help.  By just pointing out the meaning of it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: The linear span of a subspace is the subspace itself.  This is also true when the subspace is the whole space, of course.  Was there anything else side the span?  Maybe you misunderstand the word "span."  What you first described sounds like as basis.  The span of a set $S$ is the set of all finite linear combinations of vectors from $S$.  $S$ itself doesn't have to be finite.

Comment: Basis is a span too.  I have not misunderstood anything.   People are just misunderstanding my question and hence don't answer it. Maybe except for you and another answerer.  I know exactly what is a span of vectors.   My question is what it means when you say a span of a linear space or subspace.   You started to say it means the space itself. Can you expand on it?

Answer (score 1):

The span of a set with possibly infinitely many elements is defined to be the set of all *finite* linear combinations of that set. Hence as mentioned in the comments, for example $\operatorname{span}(V) = V$ for a vector space $V$.

Comment: For example.   Span (R2). Would be all possible combinationso of vectors in R2.  But eventually it would just be R2. Right?

Comment: @bengy  Yes exactly. The important point is finite linear combinations. I mention this because one might think that if we have an infinite set the also we have infinite linear combinations. In the case of $R^2$, clearly the span is contained and conversly, if I have a vector in $R^2$, then it must be in the span.

Comment: Thnx.  I think I got it.  You are the only one answering my question here since no one else understood me.  Basically what you say is.  If someone writes Span (v) and V is a vector space it would be enough for me to get finite number of vectors like the number of dimension from that V linearly independent and compute everything on them instead on V.

Answer (score 0):

It just means look at the subspace generated by some finite set of vectors.

For example, if $S=\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$, then the span of $S$ is a subspace $U \subset V$ consisting of formal linear combinations $U=a_1(1,1)+b_2(2,2)$ with $a_1,b_2 \in \mathbb R$. If $S=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, then it just happens that the span of $S$ is all of $V$, since any element of $V$ can be written in the form $a_1(1,0)+a_2(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The span of a subset of the vector space is defined in exactly the same way, regardless of how many elements are in that subset. Namely, if $V$ is the vector space and if $X$ is a subset of $V$ then $\text{Span}(X)$ is the set of all elements of $V$ which can be written in the form
$$a_1 x_1 + ... + a_K x_K
$$
where $a_1,...,a_K$ are scalars (e.g. real numbers) and where $x_1,...,x_K$ are vectors (i.e. elements of $V$).

So if you take the span of $V$ itself, you'll discover, by applying the definition, that $\text{Span}(V) = V$, for a very simple reason: for each $v \in V$ you can take $K=1$, $a_1=1$, and $x_1=v \in V$, and you'll get
$$v = 1 \cdot v = a_1 \cdot x_1
$$